# sas proc sql having with condition for positive and negative values

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I don't know how to select, in proc sql, the min for positive values of diff (to have the 25/11/2022) and the max for negatives diff (to have the 11/11/2022).

[image]

Do I need to use the case statement or having ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: @Kermit Maximum of negative value is the least negative number, so in this case -604800

Comment: @Negdo Yes thanks - realized it when writing the solution... deleting my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
data have;
    input NO_K DATE1 :DDMMYY10. diff;
    format DATE1 :DDMMYY10.;
    datalines;
055800 04/11/2022 -1209600
055800 11/11/2022 -604800
055800 25/11/2022 604800
055800 30/11/2022 1036800
;
run;




proc sql;
    create table want1 as
        select *
            from have
                where diff > 0
                having diff = min(diff) 
    ;
    create table want2 as
        select *
            from have
                where diff < 0
                having diff = max(diff) 
    ;
quit;

data want;
    set want1 want2;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below should it need to be entirely in `PROC SQL`

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select * from have
where diff = (select min(diff)
    from have
    where diff > 0)
union 
select * from have
where diff = (select max(diff)
    from have
    where diff < 0)
;
quit;
```